# Is there any way to force my external display to higher resolution?

Tags: external

Because I used this monitor before with a Nvidia RTX 3050 graphics panel on my PC. But on my new laptop that has Intel integrated GPU won't work. My laptop also has dedicated Nvidia RTX 4060 GPU.

Comment: What models are your laptop and monitor?